# On the fly Title change in ASP.Net like facebook

Tags: asp.net

i wanna have a Faceook-Feature in my website:
Everytime a user gets a Private Message, the title should be change in something like "[1 PM] TITLE",

How to do that?

Comment: How you check if user gets a message? Do you already have AJAX in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to do it is via javascript, e.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.title = "This is new title";
</script>
```

You can wrap it into some function and fire it when you need:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeTitle(str) {
    document.title = str;
}

// fire it when you need:
changeTitle("[1 PM] TITLE");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Page.Title` property to set the title on the fly.
Please look at this link - maybe can help you further.
[Specifying the title meta tags and other html headers in the master page](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages/specifying-the-title-meta-tags-and-other-html-headers-in-the-master-page-cs)

**EDIT**
If you can change you title via code then the above will do. You can change it in you `Page_Load` function according to what ever data you have.

If you want to change your title after the page has loaded and sent to the client then the only way to do so is via javascript. if the title needs server side data then AJAX will be the most convenient way (don't postback all the page just to change the title). when the data returns to the client side, you can do `document.title = <new title value>` and it will change on the fly.

Comment: I know that property the main question is how to change it dynamicly

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this in your HTML markup (I can't test now it now...):

```
<head id="head1" runat="server">
    <title>To be replaced.</title>
</head>
```

ASPX Code-behind:

```
// Add the page title to the header element.
Page.Header.Title = "HtmlHead Example";
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.page.header.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2